# How to change the key of JSONArray in java

Tags: java, json, arraylist

JSON received by POST from the front end

[{"id":"001","name":"James"},{"id":"002","name":"Emma"}]

I want to change the key of the received JSON and return it.

[{"ID":"001","FirstName":"James"},{"ID":"002","FirstName":"Emma"}]

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController{
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/test1", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<Object> post (@RequestBody List<TestDto> list){
    
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(list);

        //I want to add a process to change the JSON key here
         .......
 
        return jArray.toList();
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have to construct new JSONObjects with the altered key and insert them into a JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

I would parse it to a string using

```
 String s = new ObjectMapper().mapper.writeValueAsString(list);

   s.replace("id","ID") ;
```

and return new JSONObject(string);

Comment: Thanks for answering:)

String s = new ObjectMapper().mapper.writeValueAsString(list); of
I get an error in the mapper part.

Error: mapper cannot be resolved or is not a fieldJava(33554502)

Do I need to import?
I looked but could not find out.

Comment: you can import by : import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

Comment: What if the first name is David ?

Comment: good point so we can replace "\"id\"" instead of "id"